# Briggs and stratton twin. governor

Tags: lawn-mower, lawn

I have a Briggs twin.  The governor gear broke and I replaced it. I adjusted the governor and it still runs full tilt. I tried anther new governor gear and the same thing happens.

Comment: What instructions did you follow to adjust the governor?

Comment: throttle all the way up turn governor same direction .